# Android Service Stops background processing while its still alive

Tags: android, sockets, gps

I am developing a GPS Service Which sends data Through a Socket...
when I start my service it runs fine for few minutes and after some time the background processing stops..
while I checked running services on my android device my service was alive.

Comment: Well a bit more information is needed to answer this one. How do you realize that the service stops processing? Any log snippets - or even better code snippets?

Comment: i am not getting the data on the server side socket...
also i added some toast.maketext statement within the code block, those are also not getting executed after some time...

Comment: Possibly, there might be `SocketTimeOut` occurring causing your background connection process to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Your additional comment also doesn't help much. Probably you just lost your connection and do not reestablish it within your service?

Well, that's a wild-goose chase without any snippets of code.